# What's the geological period of the birth of the river Ganges?

Tags: geology, hydrology, rivers

> [Avatarana or Descent of the Ganges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganges#Avatarana_or_Descent_of_the_Ganges) (extracted from Wikipedia):
>   "In late May or early June every year, Hindus celebrate the avatarana
>   or descent of the Ganges from heaven to earth."

There are several Hindu versions for the birth of the river Ganges.
I'm here interested in the scientific version:

> **Question**: When (and how) this river was born (geological period)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [How Old is Our Ganga](http://www.iitk.ac.in/infocell/iitk/newhtml/storyoftheweek51.htm), the Ganges "formed as a consequence of the India-Asia collision around 55 million years ago resulting in the formation of the Himalaya. This provided a large continental mass which together with large rainfall in the catchment area and long term erosion generated /enlarged the river valleys".